# Google Apps - Wildcard MX record to handle multiple sub domain aliases

Tags: subdomain, g-suite, mx-record

I have added several wildcard MX records on my Domain Management Console, which all point to Google Email server and their backup email servers, e.g.

```
10           *.mydomain.net    ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM              3600        
20           *.mydomain.net    ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM         3600        
20           *.mydomain.net    ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM         3600        
30           *.mydomain.net    ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM           3600        
30           *.mydomain.net    ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM           3600        
30           *.mydomain.net    ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM           3600        
30           *.mydomain.net    ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM           3600
```

On the Google Apps side, I can setup [domain aliases](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=182079). That way, I can have two email addresses using the same account, e.g. john@mydomain.net and john@sub.mydomain.net.

In order for the domain alias to work, I need to setup the corresponding MX records for the domain. My question: I want to cover all possible domain aliases with the above wildcard MX records, such that whenever I add a new domain alias in Google Apps, emails to the new alias should work without any additional changes on the Domain Management side. Is this setup possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you already have that setup.  What isn't working in your current arrangement?

I suspect that you've incorrectly setup your MX records, because a request for `fraffle.mydomain.net` doesn't return any MX records.

Comment: When I try to send an email to one of the sub domains, I get the following mail: DNS Error: DNS server returned answer with no data

Comment: Add that to your question.